# AWS - Pause autoscaling after failed retries

Tags: amazon-web-services, lifecycle, autoscaling

I have setup some Autoscaling LifeCycle hooks, where some of my other applications plug on those hooks and perform various actions (deploy app update, etc.)

However, I know that at some point my apps will fail and lifecycle hooks will never be able to complete. And therefore, AWS autoscaling will keep spawning/terminating new instances and possibly eat my money and generate noise for nothing.

Is there some protections that 
  - are already in place by AWS ?
  - I can add to suspend autoscaling operations if I detect too many fails without ay success ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoScaling will keep trying to launch new EC2 Instances for 24 hours.

[Suspending and Resuming Scaling Processes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html)

> You can suspend and then resume one or more of the scaling processes
>   for your Auto Scaling group. This can be useful when you want to
>   investigate a configuration problem or other issue with your web
>   application and then make changes to your application, without
>   triggering the scaling processes.
>
> Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling can suspend processes for Auto Scaling groups
>   that repeatedly fail to launch instances. This is known as an
>   administrative suspension, and most commonly applies to Auto Scaling
>   groups that have been trying to launch instances for over 24 hours but
>   have not succeeded in launching any instances. You can resume
>   processes suspended for administrative reasons.

As far as I know, you cannot change this parameter.

Comment: What about settings some alarms on failed starts and maybe some lambda function that would edit the autoscaling group to suspend processes ? that would be a viable option no ?

Comment: I would say that is possible. Configure your alarm (or the alarm of the ASG) to send a notification to a SNS topic. That SNS topic will be the trigger for the lambda function that will change the ASG configuration. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#suspendProcesses-property . But then you would have to start the ASG manually, or think about any other alarm and lambda function.